# Why are my footnotes using symbols instead of numbers?

Tags: pdftex, footnotes, arabic

[image]I want my footnotes to be numbered with Arabic numbers. However, they have symbols instead of Arabic numbers. Although I've inserted the code `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}` the footnote continues to have a symbol and not a number.

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,abstracton]{article}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

 \begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp] \centering
  \caption{Data Sources} 
  \label{Data Sources} 
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
 \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
\footnotesize
\color{black}}
\makeatother
\copyrightbox [b] {
\begin{tabular} {llll}
\hline
variable name & unit of measure & main data source & complementary data sources\\
\hline
BLA BLA BLA & BLA BLA BLA & www.BLA.com \footnote{original data stem from BLA BLA BLA} & none\\
\end{tabular}
}{source: own representation}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE, i.e. a minimal yet complete document that actually compiles. Your code does not. At first glance, you are using way too many packages that you probably don't need.

Comment: Please make your your example is complete. Additionally your preamble is very messy and several packages are loaded more than once.

Comment: your preamble generates various errors. You shouldn't ignore them, after errors the output is random.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there is a footnote hidden in the middle of the sidewaystable and various other boxes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh so there is, odd: I thought I checked, I deleted the comment.

Comment: You load graphics after graphicx. Are you sure, this is right. Please sort your usepackages. From most standard to most uncommon. Are you familiar with the `\show` command? This is very helpful.

Comment: example code should demonstrate the problem. Test it before you post it. This still errors as sidewaystable is no longer defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tablefootnote` package provides the command `\tablefootnote` to be used in
a table or `sidewaystable` environment, where `\footnote` will not work.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{rotating} % rotate table LOAD HERE <<<<<<
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
    \footnotesize
    \color{black}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}    
    
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
 \centering
    \caption{Data Sources} 
    \label{Data Sources} 
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}         
        \copyrightbox [b] {
            \begin{tabular} {llll}
                \hline
                variable name & unit of measure & main data source & complementary data sources\\
                \hline
                BLA BLA BLA & BLA BLA BLA & www.BLA.com \tablefootnote{original data stem from BLA BLA BLA} & none\\% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
            \end{tabular}
        }{source: own representation}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Simon. Perfect, it works! Thank you so much for your support.